# O que é singleton variable em prolog?

Tags: variáveis, singleton, prolog

Estou fazendo um trabalho em Prolog e ao tentar fazer uma consulta ele diz que há "Singleton variables". Por exemplo, uma parte do código:

```
s([Policia_X, Policia_Y, Ladrao_X, Ladrao_Y]) :- pode_andar_horizontal([Policia_X, Policia_Y]).
```

Retorna o erro:

> Warning: c:/users/leila/desktop/2018.2/ia/ia/trab1.pl:35:
>           Singleton variables: [Ladrao_X,Ladrao_Y]

O que significa isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é um aviso para ajudá-la com dois erros comuns:

- Erros de ortografia nas variáveis
- Uma variável que não está a ser utilizado

Portanto, no seu caso em específico, esse aviso diz que no ficheiro `trab1.pl`, na linha `35` (que é o`:35`), pode estar a usar variáveis que não foram mais usados nessa regra ou fato. Pode significar também um erro de ortografia. No caso, de usar a variável apenas uma vez, por exemplo:

```
teste(A): - t(B, A).
```

Nesse caso, pode livrar da mensagem de aviso colocando o `(_)` a frente da variável *singleton*, neste caso a variavél `B`:

```
teste(A): - t(_B, A).
```